# Display of region borders Admin_level 4 in MapTiler plugin for QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, maptiler

I want to make a map using QGIS where the administrative boundaries of the regions will be displayed. Not all, but only the ones I need. They may change from time to time. Therefore, I think that it is not the best solution to download data from OSM every time, then add a new layer, etc. Also, layers with OSM data may differ in detail at different zoom levels from the basic MapTiler map that I plan to use.
So I decided to use MapTiler for this border task. I loaded the Basic layer.
[image]
[image]
And tried to edit it a bit.
Added a new category of symbols for region borders. For example, I need the borders of the West Pomeranian Voivodeship.  added the appropriate filter, but everything is displayed as in the first picture.
[image]
[image]
When I remove the filter with the name the West Pomeranian Voivodeship, the borders are displayed with the desired style.
[image]
[image]
Perhaps there are other options for solving this task, I will be glad for any help.